# Самый быстрый способ вытащить два числа из массива по условию

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Есть такой `numpy` массив:

```
row = [ 538  539  540  541  542  644  662  663  664  665  768 1152 1205 1243 1244
        1258 1275 1382 1399 1506 1523 1630]
```

Числа в массиве всегда идут похожим образом, то есть в порядке возрастания.

Каким образом быстрее всего вытащить из массива два числа `n`, которые соответствуют условию `n1 < a < n2`? К примеру, у меня есть число `a = 960`. В этом случае нужно вытащить из массива числа `768` и `1152`, так как `768 < 960 < 1152`.

Сейчас я просто делю массив на две части: все числа, которые меньше `a` и все, которые больше. Потом вытаскиваю из этих частей последний и первый элемент соответственно.

```
left = row[row < a][-1]
right = row[row > a][0]
```

Хотелось бы узнать самый подходящий способ и почему именно он быстрее всего. Спасибо.

Comment: Быстрее модификации бинарного поиска вряд ли что-то найдётся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо @m9_psy за комментарий под вопросом, мне удалось найти реализацию бинарного поиска в библиотеке `numpy` - [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Вроде бы то, что мне нужно.

Как я понимаю, `searchsorted` возвращает индекс, на который можно вставить в массив переданное функции значение, чтобы сортировка сохранилась.

```
index = np.searchsorted(row, a)  # Так я нашел индекс
left, right = row[index - 1], row[index]  # Получил два нужных мне числа из массива
```

Может, кому-нибудь пригодится.

Comment: да, найти что-нибудь быстрее чем `np.searchsorted()` для поиска по __отсортированным__ массивам - очень маловероятно

Comment: отметте свой ответ как правильный

Comment: @AndrioSkur пишет, что только завтра можно будет отметить